# MonoTouch: Draggable MKAnnotationView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mapkit, monodevelop, mkannotationview

I am trying to implement a draggable MKAnnotationView in MonoTouch.

In the iOS docs there is a @property called Draggable on the MKAnnotationView, but not on the Monotouch Implementation.

Is there another way to implement a draggable MKAnnotationView in Monotouch.

```
var anv = new MKAnnotationView (myAnnotation, "ILoveMonoTouch"){
      Draggable = true   <== ERROR
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason (likely a bug) this property is implemented in [`MKPinAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) not [`MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and this contradict Apple's documentation. I'll look into this and ensure it's fixed in future MonoTouch releases.

**EDIT** the property `dragState` has the same issue

**UPDATED UPDATE** this is fixed in the just released 5.0.2